# Where is gparted in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, gparted

How do I find gparted in Ubuntu, searching from the launcher sends me to Wiki or shopping?

Comment: http://gparted.org/download.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find [gparted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/) in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Ok, what is installed - apart from a lot of amazone links and shoppingbasket?

Comment: I found disks, so it had to do.

Answer (score 21):

Gparted is not installed by default. To install it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

OR

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: `sudo apt install gparted` :P

Answer (score 6):

You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

As it will most likely not be installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

gparted isn't pre-installed although it is installed in the Ubuntu -Live mode.
you can type

`$ sudo apt-get install gparted`

in terminal to install it.