# Unreadable devices

Tags: usb-drive

I have two flash drives that I have erased using *Startup Disk Creator* in Ubuntu, to make them as bootable devices. Unfortunately they have been cracked and I can not use them at all. My laptop can't identify them too.

Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you not installing **gparted** check this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/573796/464430)

1. Open **gparted** and chose your flash [image]
2. **`right click`** on your device and **Unmount**
3. format to ntfs
4. then **mount** again or open from **nautilus**

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer and it works.
Could tell me how did you got this answer?

Comment: @FSh specially this answer by luck i read many document but not solve my problem , by luck when i was trying to create new partition using gparted i noticed that gparted read my usb i tried and fortunately  help me to return back 3 usb 16 gb :D 
but in other problems, i spend much time on askubuntu reading problem and trying to solve or read answers